# Relationships in EF?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I am new to Entity Framework and I just can't figure out how relationships work in a code-first approach.

For example, consider three entities: `Users`, `Pictures`, `Posts`.

- A user can have multiple pictures.
- A post can have multiple pictures.

From a database perspective those are 3 tables + 2 junction tables (`UserPictures`, `PostPictures`).

What I have so far is not creating the foreign key relationship in the database:

```cs
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; } = new List<Picture>();
}

[Table("Pictures")]
public class Picture
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string BlobPath { get; set; }
}

[Table("Posts")]
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; } = new List<Picture>();
}
```

How can I accomplish this? Or should I simple drop the general `Pictures` table and put the paths in the junction table entry?

Comment: This does create a data model with FK relationships. There are two FKs in the Picture table, one to User and one to Post. That's a viable model. You don't need the junction tables.

Answer (score 1):

EF will use junction tables for Many-to-Many relationships, and just Foreign Keys for One-to-Many.

The basic way to distinguish between the two is to place inverse Navigation Properties on the related entity, eg if you decide that a Picture belongs to one user, but can appear in many Posts, then

```
[Table("Pictures")]
public class Picture
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string BlobPath { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts{ get; set; } = new HashSet<Post>();

}
```

In EF Core you're free to omit the Foreign Key properties and linking tables, and they'll be handled behind-the-scenes.

If you don't like the default convention-based configuration, you can use code or attribute-based [configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/) to modify the object-to-database mapping.